# How can I clear a WKWebview that is contained in a custom UITableViewCell that is reused?

Tags: ios, uitableview, wkwebview

I have a UITableView that dequeues my custom UITableViewCell.  The UITableViewCell contains a WKWebView.  In cellForRowAtIndexPath, I set the url that the WKWebView should load and the webview starts to load the page.  The problem is that the data of the cell, sometimes displays the "old" data while the new url is still loaded.

I tried to first load about:blank and I also tried `webView.loadHTMLString("", baseURL: nil)`, but it did not work, because it is an async operation.

Here is pieces of my code.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MyTableViewController.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
    cell.url = data[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
    return cell
}
```

In MyTableViewCell, I immediately start to load the html.  loadHTML(in:,forUrl:) is a private function that loads the url into the webview.

```
var url: String? {
    didSet {
        loadHTML(in:webView!, forURL:url)
    }
}
```

It will be much appreciated if someone knows how to do this properly.  Some suggestions that I have seen included, hiding the webView until it is finished loaded.  I would actually like my user to see the progress in loading.

I don't think it would be a good idea not to dequeue the UITableViewCell.  (The cell contain other controls too.)  The best I can think of right now, is to remove the WKWebView and adding it again.

Answer (score 0):

What about covering the content with an empty view as long as it is not reloaded (i guess you can check it with the wk delegate `didFinishNavigation`)
You may leave out the loading, bar tuning a bit the constraint.
It's very hacky i know, but may work if you look for a quick'n'dirty solution.

Not sure as performances how better it is, but for sure it doesn't involve recomputing the constraint as opposite to removing and re-adding the webview

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Here is the interesting part.  When I load a page that contains a video for example.  didFinishNavigation, only happens after the entire video has been loaded.  I do not really want to show a blank screen until then.  If I do not hide or blank it out, the other elements load and the video is just filled in later.  I also tried observing WKWebView.estimatedProgress and hide the webview until the first progress is received, but it is not consistent at what progress state the old data actually disappears

Comment: Then maybe loading a static empty html page or a javascript in the - tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath: ?